# JavaFX ComboBox OnChangeListener rollback change

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, listener

I'm trying to reset the selection of a `ComboBox` like follows:

```
// private ListView<MyEntityType> f_lItems

f_lItems.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<?> ov, Object t, Object t1) {
        if (t1 != null && t1 instanceof MyEntityType) {

            MyEntityType pv = (MyEntityType) t1;
            // do some condition testing
            if (condition) {
                // accept 
            } else 
                // roll back to previous item
                f_lItems.getSelectionModel().select((MyEntityType) t);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So, after trying to reset the list to the old value I get this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$177(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
```

As it seems I don't get the underlying behaviour of `List`s / `ObservableList`s for this case.

Does anyone have suggestions how I could make this work?

Thanks in advance
Adam

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reset the selection of a `ComboBox`? Do you want the `ComboBox` to have the item that is selected by default every single time that you select another one?

Comment: What you want to make?Give an example,with this approach you can have StackOverflowError error...

Comment: Lets say the selected index was 4. The user has set the index to lets say 6. In the changed handler i want to set the index back to 4 because of some internal reasons. Actually i want to realize the "are you really sure you want to change your selection" thing.

On the other hand i thought that this shouldnt be the right way anyways to do it. Maybe i have to prevent the changed event in first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment what you want is: When the (selected) value of the `ComboBox` is changed, check for a condition and then if this condition is not met, set back the value of the `ComboBox` value to the previous one.

For this you can use for example the [valueProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#valueProperty--) of the ComboBox with a listener. The listener body is just to check for the condition and the value update is nested in a `Platform.runLater{...}` block.

**Example**

In the example it is a `ComboBox` which can be set only to "Two".

```
ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<String>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four"));

cb.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        // If the condition is not met and the new value is not null: "rollback"
        if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals("Two")){

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    cb.setValue(oldValue);
                }});
        }
    }
});
```

... or you can use the [selectedItemProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty--) also with the same structure ...

```
cb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal)->{
    if(newVal != null && !newVal.equals("Two")){
        Platform.runLater(() -> cb.setValue(oldVal));
    }
});
```

**Note:** This solution is not to "prevent" the selection, just as in the title: "roll-back" an already performed selection.

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!