# JavaFX ListView add "change" EventFilter or prevent change event

Tags: listview, javafx, eventfilter

I want to implement a UI behaviour which asks the user to confirm a selected value change in a ListView or ChecbBox once the user has selected a different value than it was before.

For this i would like to consume the changed event if the user has decided to not change the value.

Tried it with the following approach, but i cant find a suitable EventType though.

```
// f_listItems is a ListView
    f_listItems.addEventFilter(eventType, (event) -> { 
        if (userschoice == false) {
            event.consume(); 
        } 
    });
```

All Types i see are Mouse and KeyEvents which i could filter for, but this is not helpful in my case. Am i following the right track or should i use a completely different approach?

I have already tried to "accept the change" and reset the value in the change handler, but this lead to different ugly problems. ([JavaFX ComboBox OnChangeListener rollback change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931195/javafx-combobox-onchangelistener-rollback-change))

I guess to prevent the change to be fired in first place would be the cleaner solution.

Thanks in advance
Adam

Comment: Probably the "proper" way to do what you describe is to write a selection model and install it on the list view. That would be a bit of a pain...

Comment: No, it is not a duplcate of that question. It is even in the question: for `MouseEvents` you can simply consume. This question is about how to have a "pre-selection" action on a ListView.

Comment: Thanks James_D and DVarga for clarifying ;) So i guess im gonna have to implement my own selection model.